# .NET Why does "Anchor" not take Toolstrip into account?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have created a form and added a ToolStrip to it.

Then I added a big button and anchored it to all sides.

Then I created a second button that would set the ToolStrip visible and invisible:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.ToolStrip1.Visible = Not Me.ToolStrip1.Visible

End Sub
```

However, when I make the ToolStrip invisible, the big button does not change its size and position.

Does anybody know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us enough of the code so we can see the order of creation and all the properties of these two controls.

Comment: Why would it?  Hiding the tool strip does not change the size of the form, and the button is anchored to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make things work as you expect by using a `Panel` to host the controls, rather than the `Form`.

From the perspective of an empty form:

1. Add the `ToolStrip`
2. Add a `Panel`
3. Set the `Panel.DockStyle` to Fill
4. Add all the rest of your controls to the Panel

Now the panel will automatically resize based on the visible status of the ToolStrip.

Comment: Using a TableLayoutPanel is even better!