# .NET Layout (Anchor, Dock, LayoutPanel)

Tags: .net, winforms, layout

I have an application that contains a menubar, an explorer bar and a grid control.
The grid control will always be shown, but the menubar and the explorer bar can be set to hidden by the user.

I was hoping that I could leave all the resizing and layouting work to Windows, but I guess I will have to do it myself if I don't find a proper solution.

My application looks like this:

[image]

You can see that there is a commandbar on the top (may be set to invisible) and an explorerbar (may be set to invisible). 
And you can also see that with the default anchor / docking that MS provides, my application goes berzerk.

I can also not use a TableLayoutPanel because the number of cols and rows is not equal.

Does anybody have any idea how to layout my controls conveniently?
Unfortunately I have not seen any other application that has a similar layout as my application, so I don't have any real reference.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450742/net-why-does-anchor-not-take-toolstrip-into-account/23741179#23741179

Comment: It is better to use devexpress control like [LayoutControl](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/)

Comment: This:  "I can also not use a TableLayoutPanel because the number of cols and rows is not equal."  Why not?  The number of rows vs cols is irrelevant.  I've made some pretty wicked layouts work in `TableLayoutPanel`.  It would be my #1 suggestion to you.